# spectral clustering eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, eigenvalue

What do the eigenvalues and eigenvectors in spectral clustering physically mean. I see that if `λ_0 = λ_1 = 0` then we will have 2 connected components. But, what does `λ_2,...,λ_k` tell us. I don't understand the algebraic connectivity by multiplicity.

Can we draw any conclusions about the tightness of the graph or in comparison to two graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smaller the eigenvalue, the less connected. 0 just means "disconnected".

Consider this a value of what share of edges you need to cut to produce separate components. The cut is orthogonal to the eigenvector - there is supposedly some threshold t, such that nodes below t should go into one component, above t to the other.

Answer (score 0):

That depends somewhat on the algorithm.  For several of the spectral algorithms, the eigenstuff can be easily run through Principal Component Analysis to reduce the display dimensionality for human consumption.  Power iteration clustering vectors are more difficult to interpret.

As Mr.Roboto already noted, the eigenvector is normal to the division brane (a plane after a Gaussian kernel transformation).  Spectral clustering methods are generally not sensitive to density (is that what you mean by "tightness"?) per se -- they find data gaps.  For instance, it doesn't matter whether you have 50 or 500 nodes within a unit sphere forming your first cluster; the game changer is whether there's clear space (a nice gap) instead of a thin trail of "bread crumb" points (a sequence of tiny gaps) leading to another cluster.